# How can I pass dynamic value using regular expression in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter-plugins

How can I pass dynamic value using regular expression in JMeter.

[image]
I need to pass the payment id from request to subsequent request.

[image]

---

Tried with that...But the default value only passing as shown in the image...[image]

[image].imgur.com/HMeXa.png

Answer (score 1):

The primary way to pass the dynamic value in Performance Testing (using any tool) is through Correlation.

Correlation is extracting value from one of the requests which can be used in the subsequent request or any of the request which must be executed further.

Steps for correlating:

(1) Create a Test Plan- Either Template or Manual

(2) Add required listener, sampler, pre-processor, post-processor

(3) There might be an HTTP request with dynamic value -> highlighted (session-id, etc.)
[image]

(4) Add regular expression extractor to the request with required boundaries. Every dynamic value requires a set of Regular expression.

Ex:
(.+?) 
. - is used for search (a-z) [0-9]
+ is used for repeatitive 
? is used for -might or might not be under

like below
[image]

These are the steps that will help you achieve Correlation in JMeter. Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggestion...But i am unable to pass the valuer with Regular expression extractor..

Comment: Hi Syed, It might happen due to below reasons
1. The selected boundaries are incorrect
2. Occurrence (Response body, Header or number)
3. Also sometimes the boundaries are dynamic too
4. Last but most important one, if the regular expression is incorrect. 
Therefore, if you could share your response body with us. We would be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

You can simply select *URL* as *Field to check* and capture the end of the URL and place in a variable, which can be used afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Changes made as shown in the image...but it only passing the value  which i have configured in subsequent request

Answer (score 0):

Here i have attached my response body[image]

Comment: @ImpactQA here i have attached my response body. in that response body i need to capture the payment id which is dynamic for every request and need to send in subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change "Field to check" to `Body`
2. Change Regular Expression to be:

   ```
   PaymentID=(\d+)"
   ```

Other settings look fine

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)